# How to update Kafka consumer max.request.size config while using Spark structured stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

Spark `readStream` for Kafka fails with the following errors:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException (The message
>   is 1166569 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum
>   request size you have configured with the max.request.size
>   configuration.)

How do we bump up the `max.request.size`?

Code:

```scala
val ctxdb = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "ip:port")
  .option("subscribe","topic")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option(" failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .option("max.request.size", "15728640")
```

We have tried to update `option("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "15728640")` with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `kafka` prefix to the writer stream setting:

```
.option("kafka.max.request.size", "15728640")
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval, with "kafka." prefix the configuration options are getting passed to kafka consumer.

Comment: But, currently still getting the same error wrt message size and the above option is not recognized
 "WARN consumer.ConsumerConfig: The configuration 'max.request.size' was supplied but isn't a known config."
kakfa version: 0.10.2.1

Comment: @user2286963 Because that's a *producer* config. Are you using the built in kafka producer in Spark?

Comment: Our producers are external, and they are pushing just fine. Our consumers are failing.
`server.properties: message.max.bytes=10000000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=15728640
max.request.size=15728641`
What option do I need to use on consumer side to make it read the large messages?

Comment: @user2286963 Then you're looking for `fetch.message.max.bytes`. Also, you need to make sure your topic is configured on the brokers with the right request size, which I'm assuming you've already set since your producer is enable to produce these large files.

Comment: Yuval, Please ignore the above comments. I read from 1 topic, and write to many. I configured the writer with option("kafka.max.request.size", "15728640") and it work.

Comment: Reference for adding Kafka specific options using "kafka" prefix: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations (Kafka’s own configurations can be set via DataStreamReader.option with kafka. prefix, e.g, stream.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")).